# Manually trigger a post_updated webhook in Discourse

Tags: discourse

I’m looking to make a change to the raw data for a bunch of my Discourse posts in a rake task and then re-cook the result.

When this happens I also want to trigger the webhook for post_updated

What’s the best practice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in another forum, thanks to [Guo Xiang Tan](https://meta.discourse.org/u/tgxworld) for the answer.

> From your rails console, you can run WebHook.enqueue_post_hooks(:post_edited, post). Make sure Sidekiq is running though.